# How to find the changes done to a particular kernel module through all releases

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, history, source

I need to access source code of all past versions of read_write.c under /fs/ from 3.10 to 5.3.

So far I had to go through https://elixir.bootlin.com/ repeatedly and look at every single version that has read_write.c changes. I do not want to download the entire complete kernel collection 3.10 through 5.3. However I also want to see the differences even in minor versions. Is there anyway I can download the particular source code of a module for any given version (does not matter if I need to do it manually, I can always use diff and locate when the changes happened.) or see the version history of a module throughout all releases including minor versions.

Comment: "I do not want to download the entire complete kernel collection 3.10 through 5.3." ... so you are opposed to cloning the git repository?

Comment: I am opposed to downloading the entire kernel source code, I just need read_write.c. Can I do that through the git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Because git doesn’t store individual files’ history, there’s no direct way to download a single file’s history (using only git). There are some web services which will show you all the commits affecting a single file, even on large repositories such as the kernel; for example, [GitHub’s list of commits on `fs/read_write.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master/fs/read_write.c).

If you want to have a local history of only `fs/read_write.c`, here’s one way, although it still involves (temporarily) downloading the full kernel repository (somewhere over a gigabyte nowadays):

```
mkdir ~/linux-fs-read_write
cd !$
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo fs/read_write.c > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add origin https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
git fetch origin master
git checkout !$
git filter-repo --path=fs/read_write.c --force
```

The last step uses [`git-filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) and results in a 130MiB tree with only `fs/read_write.c` and its history (since 2.6.12-rc2).

Given the context in which you’re trying to do this, there is one disadvantage to only having the commits touching a specific file: it becomes difficult to tie each change to a given release tag.